# How can I increment a number by one after it reaches midnight inside of a data attribute tag?

Tags: jquery, date

I have HTML tags like so, they activate a calendar pop up modal. The number passed after the comma inside of 'data-accesso-params', is how many days until December 1st.

```
<td class="green">
     <a data-accesso-module="calendar" data-accesso-params="WintTickEN,88" href="#" class="date">1</a>
</td>
<td class="green">
     <a data-accesso-module="calendar" data-accesso-params="WintTickEN,89" href="#" class="date">2</a>
</td> 
. . . and so on to 31
```

When the clock turns midnight, the number will obviously need to increase by one, so that the calendar aligns with the date. I could do this by hand, but this will be tiresome and very time-consuming.

Am I on the right track? Or do I need to do something else? I know the below is useless, or, near enough anyway, but I will need to find the number first after the comma, and then manipulate that, so perhaps a RegExp would be better?

```
var a = $('a.date').data('accesso-params');
var _var = number++
$('a.date').data('accesso-params,WintTickEN, + _var++ );
```

Comment: Need to use `split()` or regex to get the original number. Or do the date math yourself before updating it. Also not clear if you have multiples or you are showing us expected results of just one. If multiples you need to loop over the instances

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = $('a.date').data('accesso-params');
var theData = a.split(",")[1];
var theText = theData[0];
var theNumber = ++theData[1];
a = $('a.date').data('accesso-params', theText + "," + theNumber);
```

However, a better approach is to use separate `data-` attributes for separate pieces of data. That way you'll avoid parsing the text in the `data-` parameter and you can update the number as appropriate. I.e.

```
var theNumber = $('a.date').data('accesso-params-num');
$('a.date').data('accesso-params-num', ++theNumber);
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks! Nothing I can do about separating the `data-` attributes I am afraid. When it comes to adding one after midnight, can I use Javascript's date methods or should I use another way? Thanks very much.